# Chaining Scala nested futures

Tags: scala, future

I have some troubles chaining futures in Scala. Suppose I have the following:

```
def fetchInts(s: String): Future[List[Int]] = Future {
  (0 to s.length).toList
}

def fetchChars(a: Int): Future[List[Char]] = Future {
  ("a" * a).toList
}
```

and for a given `String` I want to fetch `Int`s and then for each fetched `Int` I want to fetch `Char`s, all as async as possible. The output type I want to get is `Future[List[(Int, List[Char])]]` and semantically I want to do something like that:

```
def fetch(s: String): Future[List[(Int, List[Char])]] = {
  for {
    as <- fetchInts(s)
    a <- as
    cs <- fetchChars(a)
  } yield (a, cs)
}
```

The above will not type-check as I mix `List` and `Future` monads so I have so far come up with:

```
def fetch(s: String): Future[List[(Int, List[Char])]] = {
  val fas: Future[List[Int]] = fetchInts(s)
  fas.flatMap { as: List[Int] =>
    val res = as.map { a: Int =>
      val fcs: Future[List[Char]] = fetchChars(a)
      fcs.flatMap(cs => Future((a, cs)))
    }
    Future.sequence(res)
  }
}
```

This type-checks but looks clumsy and I have some doubts if this is thread-optimal as I do not fully grasp the semantics of `Futures.sequence()`. Is there some other simpler, idiomatic way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for-comprehension in Scala, is maps and flatMaps over the same entity. In your fetch method, it is over futures. The reason it doesn't work, is that `as` is `List[Int]`, and not a future. In this use case, it will be easier to write it without for-comprehension. You can try the following:

```
def fetch(s: String): Future[List[(Int, List[Char])]] = {
  fetchInts(s).flatMap { ints =>
    Future.traverse(ints)(i =>
      fetchChars(i).map { chars =>
        i -> chars
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The result of:

```
println(Await.result(fetch("abrakadabra"), 2.seconds))
```

Is:

```
List((0,List()), (1,List(a)), (2,List(a, a)), (3,List(a, a, a)), (4,List(a, a, a, a)), (5,List(a, a, a, a, a)), (6,List(a, a, a, a, a, a)), (7,List(a, a, a, a, a, a, a)), (8,List(a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a)), (9,List(a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a)), (10,List(a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a)), (11,List(a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a)))
```

From Scala docs [Future.traverse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse%5BA,B,M%5BX%5D%3C:IterableOnce%5BX%5D%5D(in:M%5BA%5D)(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future%5BB%5D)(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom%5BM%5BA%5D,B,M%5BB%5D%5D,implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BM%5BB%5D%5D):

> Asynchronously and non-blockingly transforms a IterableOnce[A] into a Future[IterableOnce[B]] using the provided function A => Future[B]. This is useful for performing a parallel map.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/y8fSn1GnQryvSKivqcwnRA/6).

If after all you do want to use for comprehension, you can try:

```
def fetch1(s: String): Future[List[(Int, List[Char])]] = {
  for {
    ints <- fetchInts(s)
    result <- Future.traverse(ints)(i => for {
        chars <- fetchChars(i)
      } yield i -> chars)
  } yield result
}
```

Comment: More efficient and looks better. - More efficient because you avoid traversing the **List** twice and you avoid creating a bunch of **Futures** beforehand. - Looks better is highly subjective but I am pretty sure that if you do the change in this example you will see that it becomes less nested.